# Powershell else if and text color beginner

Tags: powershell

I have an assignment due and I have some problems with my code.
When the statement is True it has to print a text in the color green, and when its false the text has to be red. I'm having trouble with that as well as getting it to print true or false.

This is my code so far

```
$cpr = '123456-1212' -match '\d\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d'

if $cpr{
    Executes when the Boolean expression is true
}else {
    Executes when the Boolean expression is false
}
```

If I print

```
'123456-1212' -match '\d\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d'
```

by it self it has no problem giving a true of false value.

Comment: [PowerShell learning resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/more-powershell-learning?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$cpr = '123456-1212' -match '\d\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d'

if($cpr)
{
    write-host -foregroundcolor yellow "Statement is true"
}
else
{
    write-host -foregroundcolor red "Statement is false"
}
```

Comment: regex has a way to say "this many". i would use something like `'\d{6}-\d{4}'` for the target pattern just because i have problems counting repeated repetitions ... [*grin*]